# Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException thrown for behat.yml

Tags: symfony, yaml, behat

My **behat.yml** looks like this:

```
 default:
  firefox:
   context:
       parameters:
            Browser_Name: firefox
   extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:            
            base_url: https://google.com
            javascript_session: selenium2
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
   [Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]  Indentation problem in "D:\\mypgms\\behat.yml" at line 7 (near " extensions:").
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: that has nothing to do with symfony or behat. YAML uses 2 or 4 space indention, never tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indentation of your YAML file is inconsistent.

Please see the YAML spec's chapter [indentation spaces](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2519916).

Either use 2 or 4 spaces indentation consistently across your YAML config file to resolve the issue.

**example with 2-space indentation:**

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:            
      base_url: "https://base-url.com"
      # ...
  context:
    parameters:
      class:    Your\Custom\Context
      base_url: "https://context-base-url.com"
      # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the Info dude.I didnt know , even a space can make difference . It solved my problem ..

Comment: You seem to be quite new to stackoverflow and I see you haven't accepted any answers to your questions yet. As your issue has been resolved with the help of my answer - please accept the answer by clicking the green "V" next to it. This way other users will know the problem has already been solved when browsing through the questions. Thanks and happy coding.